Prove $d\varphi$ is Lie algebra isomorphism
I'm trying to solve Exercise 1.3.8.4 in GTM255 R.Goodman, N.R.Wallach Symmetry, Representations, and Invariants.
Let $V$ denote the vector space of symmetric $2\times2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. If $x,y\in V$, define $B(x,y)=\det(x+y)-\det(x)-\det(y)$. We can show that $B$ is not degenerate.
If $g\in \mathbf{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ define $\varphi(g)\in \mathbf{GL}(V)$ by $\varphi(g)(v)=gvg^t$. We can show that $\varphi:\mathbf{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})\to\mathbf{SO}(V,B)$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $\{\pm I\}$.

I want to prove that:
$\varphi$ is continuous and d$\varphi$ is a Lie algebra isomorphism. Use this result to prove that the image of  $\varphi$ is open.

I have proved that $\varphi$ is continuous and d$\varphi$ is injective:
Continuous:
Suppose that there is a sequence $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converging to $g$. This means $||g_n-g||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(g_n^{ij}-g^{ij})^2}\to 0$. We call the entries $g_n^{ij}$ in the matrix $g_n=[g_n^{ij}]$. Given $v\in V$, we have
\begin{align*}
||\varphi(g_n)v-\varphi(g)v||&=||g_nvg_n^t-gvg^t||\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}((g_nvg_n^t)^{ij}-(gvg^t)^{ij})^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}(\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{s=1}^ng_n^{is}v^{sj}g_n^{jm}-\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{s=1}^ng^{is}v^{sj}g^{jm})^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}(\sum_{m,s}v^{sj}(g_n^{is}g_n^{jm}-g^{is}g^{jm}))^2}\to 0
\end{align*}
which means $\varphi$ is continuous.
Injective:
Suppose that $X\in \text{Lie}(\mathbf{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}))$ such that $\text{d}\varphi(X)=0$.
So we have:
$$\text{d}\varphi(X)=0\Rightarrow \varphi(\exp(X))=\exp(\text{d}\varphi(X))=\exp(0)=I\Rightarrow \exp(X)=I\Rightarrow X=0$$.

But for d$\varphi$ is surjective and the image of $\varphi$ is open, I don't know how to do it.
Any comments are welcome!

Surjectivity:
In finite-dimensional vector spaces, if a linear map is injective and its domain and codomain have the same dimension, then the map is necessarily surjective. This is a fundamental result in linear algebra.
Basis and Dimension of $\operatorname{sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$:
$\operatorname{sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $2\times 2$ real matrices with trace zero.
Basis:
\begin{align*}
E = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
F = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
H = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Any matrix in $\operatorname{sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$ can be expressed in the form $aE + bF + cH$, with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the dimension of $\operatorname{sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$ is $3$.
Dimension of $\operatorname{so}(V, B)$:
$V$ is the space of symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices.
It has a basis:
\begin{align*}
S_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
S_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
S_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Again,any matrix in $V$ can be expressed in the form $xS_1 + yS_2 + zS_3$, where $x, y$, and $z$ are real numbers. Therefore, the dimension of $V$ is $3$.
$\operatorname{so}(V, B)$ is the set of skew-symmetric transformations on $V$ with respect to the bilinear form $B$. Because any linear transformation on $V$ has a $3 \times 3$ matrix representation, and skew-symmetric matrices have three degrees of freedom, the dimension of $\operatorname{so}(V, B)$ is also $3$, given that $V$ has dimension $3$.
The Image of $\phi$ is Open:
By the Open Mapping Theorem, $\phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$ contains a neighborhood $U$ of the identity element $I\in SO(V, B)$. That is, there exists an open set $U$ in $SO(V, B)$ such that $I \in U$ and $U \subset \phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$.
Now, consider an arbitrary element $h \in \phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$. Since $\phi$ is a group homomorphism, for any $g \in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$, we have $\phi(g) = h$.
Then, $hU$ is an open set in $SO(V, B)$, and $h \in hU$. Moreover, since $U \subset \phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$, we have $hU \subset \phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$. This means that a neighborhood $hU$ of $h$ is entirely contained in $\phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$.
Since $h$ is an arbitrary element of $\phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$, we have shown that every point in $\phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$ has a neighborhood contained within $\phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$. Therefore, $\phi(SL(2, \mathbb{R}))$ is an open set in $SO(V, B)$.

Please use MathJax.
